# Create object using user input

Tags: c++, function, object, struct, parameters

I want to create number of structure objects using input from user
for example: 
I want to accept user value `n` and create `n` number of objects and pass these objects to a function where I initialize the variables to them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    int roll_no;
    char name[20];
};

void get_input(student p[],int n1)
{   
    for(int i=1;i<=n1;i++)
    {   
        cout<<"Enter Roll Number ";
        cin>>p[i].roll_no;
        cout<<"\n Enter Name of the student: ";
        cin>>p[i].name;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int n;
    cout<<"How many student details would you want to enter: ";
    cin>>n;
    //Want to create number of object based on input n
    student p[n];
    get_input(student p[],n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable length arrays are not allowed in C++. Use a `std::vector<student>` instead.

Comment: @nwp what do you mean? `cin >> n; student p[n];` works perfectly fine. To OP: well, what is the question? I see a lot of typos/basic errors but can't really post an answer to non-existing question

Comment: @Fureeish Then you are probably using some non-standart compiler extension.

Comment: @Fureeish your compiler may support it as a language extension. It won't work at all if you use a compiler that does not support such extension.

Comment: I'm actually surprised. I'm not experienced C++ user (still student) but all the compilers (default Code::Blocks, newest MinGWs..) I've been using allowed me to do that

Comment: @Fureeish Those are not compilers. They may all be using gcc which supports variable length arrays by default.

Comment: @Fureeish If you set the standard to `-std=c++14` instead of `-std=gnu-c++14` you should at least get warnings about using a non-standard extension.

Comment: What is your question?  Does your code not work?  (Incidentally, you should add `#include <string>` and change the declaration of `name ` to `std::string name;`.  That way you won't run in problems if 'George Alexander Louis Windsor' enrols - actually I would overrun 20 characters if I used my middle name.)

Comment: The name of the array in `main` is "p", not "student p[]".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, seems I lack basic knowledge. Thank you for that information!

Comment: Also, a collection with k elements is indexed from 0 to k-1, not 1 to k. You should get one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: student p[n] is array of objects here I am trying to create n objects based on user input

Comment: @nwp what is the syntax for using vectors and creating objects  i have used this--  error: ‘p’ was not declared in this scope
     std::vector<student> p(n);

Comment: @Step You probably did something silly like forgot `#include <vector>`. The answers show how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your example.

The first problem is `student p[n];`. This is not strictly valid c++. Some compilers allow it *as an extension*. Without knowing which compiler you are using, and with what flags, I'll assume this is part of the problem. The typical solution for this problem is to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). An `std::vector` works in many ways like an array of variable size. `std::vector<student> p(n);` will create a vector named `p` containing `n` default constructed `student` objects.

The next problem is `get_input(student p[],n);`. It's unnecessary and incorrect to name the type when passing an argument. Just write `get_input(p,n);`. After all, you didn't specify that `n` is `int` when you called `get_input`. However, since `p` is an `std::vector` now, we need to add `.data()` to fetch a pointer to the actual data. It becomes `get_input(p.data(), n);`.

The final critical issue is the loop `for (int i = 1; i <= n1; i++)`. Imagine `n` is 3. The values `i` will take are 1, 2 and 3. However, arrays are indexed starting at 0. If `n` is 3, you want to access the elements 0, 1 and 2. The correct loop is `for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)`.

These changes will allow your example to *work* but there are still many improvements that can be made.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    int roll_no;
    char name[20];
};

void get_input(student p[], int n1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Roll Number ";
        cin >> p[i].roll_no;
        cout << "\n Enter Name of the student: ";
        cin >> p[i].name;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int n;
    cout << "How many student details would you want to enter: ";
    cin >> n;
    //Want to create number of object based on input n
    std::vector<student> p(n);
    get_input(p.data(), n);


    return 0;
}
```

Consider using `std::string` instead of `char name[20]`. You won't have to guess how long a name might be, and you don't risk undefined behavior from having longer names.

```
struct student
{
    int roll_no;
    std::string name;
};
```

Consider passing `p` by reference, instead of using a pointer and size.

```
// Declaration / definition
void get_input(std::vector<student> & p)

// Usage
get_input(p);
```

Consider using a ranged based for loop instead of a regular for loop.

```
void get_input(std::vector<student> & p)
{
    // for each student in p
    for (student & s : p)
    {
        cout << "Enter Roll Number ";
        cin >> s.roll_no;
        cout << "\n Enter Name of the student: ";
        cin >> s.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `vector` of `student`: Here is some example code of how you can do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

struct student
{ int roll_no;
  char name[20];
};

 void get_input(vector<student> & p1, int n1)
{   
    for (int i=0; i<n1; i++) 
    { 
        student s;
        cout<<"Enter Roll Number: ";
        cin>>s.roll_no;
        cout<<"\n Enter Name of the student: ";
        cin>>s.name;
        p1.push_back(s);
    }
}

int main()
{

    int n;
    cout<<"How many student details would you want to enter: ";
    cin>>n;
    //Want to create number of object based on input n
    vector<student> p;
    get_input(p, n);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Francois thanks a lot it helped me clear a lot of concepts. Thanks to Rama for letting me know different approach