# Create player objects based on the number of players from user input?

Tags: c++, oop, vector

Background:
I have created a player class and I want to ask the user how many players are going to play the game? Based on the user input I am trying to create that many instances of the player class. However, I used the following links to help me: 
[Create object using user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092911/create-object-using-user-input) 
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/197342/ 
So, I tried their solution:

```
#include "Player.h"

int main() {

    int totalPlayers = -1;
    cout << "Enter total number of players: ";
    while ((totalPlayers < 1) && (totalPlayers > 5)) {
        cout << "How many players will be playing? (1-5): ";
        cin >> totalPlayers;
    }
    vector<Player> players(totalPlayers);

    system("pause");
}
```

I get the error: **Unhandled exception at 0x763F40B2 in 16LinearChess.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x003BF690.** 
So, I googled this exact error and found this link: [Error : std::length_error at memory location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964441/error-stdlength-error-at-memory-location) 
So, firstly his code was no-where related to mine, but the error was same. I did not understand the answer, but I thought that I had to create the instances using heap memory. So I tried that:

```
#include "Player.h"

int main() {

    int totalPlayers = -1;
    cout << "Enter total number of players: ";
    while ((totalPlayers < 1) && (totalPlayers > 5)) {
        cout << "How many players will be playing? (1-5): ";
        cin >> totalPlayers;
    }
    vector<Player> *players = new Player(totalPlayers);
    delete[] players;

    system("pause");
}
```

I got two errors:
 **Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0144   a value of type "Player *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "std::vector<Player, std::allocator> *"   16LinearChess   D:\Keshav\Programming Languages\C++\Beginner\01 Michael Dawson\16LinearChess\LinearChess.cpp    64**


**Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "Player::Player" matches the argument list   16LinearChess   D:\Keshav\Programming Languages\C++\Beginner\01 Michael Dawson\16LinearChess\LinearChess.cpp**

This is my Player class:

```
#include <iostream>

class Player : public Board {
protected:
    int m_position;
    Log logger;
    int m_playerNumber;
public: 
    static int m_numberOfPlayers;
    Player() :m_position(0) {
        ++m_numberOfPlayers; 
        m_playerNumber = m_numberOfPlayers;
    }

    void m_SetPlayerPosition(int &position) {
        if ((position < 0) || (position > 100)) {
            m_position = 0;
            logger.Error("Position cannot be less than or greater than 100. Your position has been reset to 0 because you fell out of the map.");
        }
        else {
            m_position = position;
        }
        m_SetBoardPosition(m_position, m_numberOfPlayers); // update the position on the board.
    }

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &os, Player &player) {
        os << "Player position on board: " << player.m_position << "\nPlayer Number: " << player.m_playerNumber << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};

int Player::m_numberOfPlayers = 0; // initializing total number of players.
```

Thank You!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220062/discussion-on-question-by-programming-rage-create-player-objects-based-on-the-nu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your while loop:

```cpp
    int totalPlayers = -1;
    cout << "Enter total number of players: ";
    while ((totalPlayers < 1) && (totalPlayers > 5)) {
        cout << "How many players will be playing? (1-5): ";
        cin >> totalPlayers;
    }
```

The while loop will only run if the condition is true, but the condition can never be true since no number can be smaller than 1, but also greater than 5. And since the condition is not true, the while loop will never run, and `totalPlayers` will be equal to `-1`, which is something you never want if you're trying to access an array index.

Change it to this: `totalPlayers < 1 || totalPlayers > 5` with an `||` instead, and you should be fine.

And for the error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x763F40B2 in 16LinearChess.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x003BF690.
```

Your code threw an exception because `totalPlayers` is equal to -1. So you basically did this:

```cpp
vector<Player> players(-1);
```

Which makes no sense since you are creating an array that hold -1 elements? So the code threw an *exception* telling you that something is wrong. The `std::length_error` should give a hint about what's wrong.

Also like many of the comments have stated, don't do this:

```cpp
vector<Player> *players = new Player(totalPlayers);
```

The whole purpose of a `vector` is so you don't do that. Your first example works fine:

```cpp
vector<Player> players(totalPlayers);
```

Comment: Ok so if -1 wraps around to the largest unsigned int value, why does it not create that many instances then? To prevent some memory problem?

Comment: it doesn't. you stored `-1` to an int variable. int variable can store negatives. if you stored it in an `unsigned int` on the other hand...

Comment: @user4581301: But you had a different contribution which was much more valuable to be honest good sir.

Comment: or if you're talking about the passing it to the vector, then it wouldn't create too many instances because a vector can only hold so many elements

Comment: @DynamicSquid but Human-Compiler says that it will wrap to the highest unsigned int value in his answer.

Comment: `std::size_t` is guaranteed to be able to express the maximum size of any object (including any array) in C++. This means the bounds for the largest object is finite in the language. The `size_type` on containers must, similarly, be able to represent the largest size in that container; but for any type where `sizeof(T)` is larger than `1`, the max number of representable objects must also accordingly be less than the max value `size_t` can hold. This means that there are some lengths of sequences that fundamentally cannot be addressed at all -- hence `length_error` catches this early

Comment: Basically: `length_error` guards user-errors where a resize value that is requested exceeds a fundamental maximum that the container could not ever feasibly hold

Comment: `size_t` is the same as `unsigned int`

Comment: or, on visual studio at least

Comment: @DynamicSquid you mean unsigned int? If so then what is the point of having two different names? Or is there a difference?

Comment: or to be more specific, it is used to represent unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned short, etc. it's returned in places like the std::vector.size() where a generic unsigned type is used. it's a little hard to explain, but you could try reading more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732319/difference-between-size-t-and-unsigned-int#:~:text=It%20is%20a%20type%20able,specified%20by%20the%20data%20model.

Answer (score 2):

`std::length_error` occurs if `std::vector` attempts to resize to a size that is above the `max_size()`. Most often, this happens from a bad input -- such as `-1` which will be converted to the largest `unsigned` value for `std::vector<T>::size_type`.

---

Judging by the code you shared, the problem is actually due to your `while` loop condition:

```cpp
    while ((totalPlayers < 1) && (totalPlayers > 5))
```

It is not possible for `totalPlayers` to be both simultaneously less than `1` *and* greater than `5` -- so this loop is never entered. Since the default value you assign to `totalPlayers` is `-1`, the size you resize to overflows and becomes the largest `unsigned` value -- which triggers the `std::length_error`.

Fixing this condition should fix your error.

Comment: Ooh I never know it wraps around to the largest unsigned value. But wait! If it does, should it not create the instances then? Should it not create the largest amount of possible instances?

Comment: The `std::length_error` exception gets thrown if the requested size is larger than `std::vector<T>::max_size()`. Since `-1` translates to an unsigned value with all bits set, on a 32-bit system this would be a number of `2^32-1` instances (4,294,967,295 instances) -- which is most likely larger than `max_size()`. This would account for why the exception is being thrown rather than resizing

Comment: Aah so they implemented a safety-feature there! Or, you simply cannot create that many instances due to the size of one instance as it has its data members and may lead to memory leaks right?

Comment: Not memory leaks, but a coarse metric that "no one" has enough memory to allocate an array that big. Leak is when you ask for a resource (file, block of memory, a horse), you get it, (which did not happen in your failure case) and you don't put it away when you are done so no one can find it if they need it again. It's like when your brother doesn't put the screwdriver back. You either have to get a new screwdriver or abandon the job that required the screwdriver.

Comment: Note you can often request far, far more storage than you actually have. Most modern operating systems will allow you to have memory, but not give it to you until you actually use it. And even then they may only give you the little bit you just used. It's possible to successfully get a Zounds... big array and then crash later when the OS can't provide the promised memory. In the meantime when it runs out of RAM, [it could start using anything else it can use for storage, like the hard drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).